# How can I change the "account already exists" message in Django allauth?

Tags: django, django-allauth

When trying to log in with a social account while there already being an account with that email, the following message shows:

`An account already exists with this e-mail address. Please sign in to that account first, then connect your Google account.`

Now I would like to change that message. At first I tried to override `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'mymodule.forms.MySignupForm'` and gave it my own `raise_duplicate_email_error` method, but that method is never called.

The form looks like this:

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    boolflag = forms.BooleanField()

    def raise_duplicate_email_error(self):
        # here I tried to override the method, but it is not called
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            _("An account already exists with this e-mail address."
              " Please sign in to that account."))

    def signup(self, request, user):
        # do stuff to the user and save it
```

So the question is: How can I change that message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the `raise_duplicate_email_error` method to be called you must inherit from a form class that actually calls `self.raise_duplicate_email_error()`! However you are just inheriting from `forms.Form`!

Let's take a look at the code of `forms.py` at https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/forms.py. We can see that `raise_duplicate_email_error` is a method of `BaseSignupForm` (and is called from its `clean_email` method).

So you need to inherit from either `allauth.account.forms.BaseSignupForm` or `allauth.account.forms.SignupForm` (which also inherits from `BaseSignupForm` and adds some more fieldds to it).

**Update after OP's comment** (that the `BaseSignupForm` is derived from the `_base_signup_form_class()` function, that itself imports the form class defined in the `SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS setting` ): Hmm you are right. The problem is that the `raise_duplicate_email_error` and `clean_email` methods of `BaseSignupForm` don't call the same-named methods of their ancestors through super (so your `raise_duplicate_email_error` is never called).

Let's see what the view does: If you have added the line `url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),` to your urls.py (which is the usual thing to do for django-allauth), you'll see the line `url(r"^signup/$", views.signup, name="account_signup"),` in the file https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/13edcfef0d7e8f0de0003d6bcce7ef58119a5945/allauth/account/urls.py and then in the file 
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/13edcfef0d7e8f0de0003d6bcce7ef58119a5945/allauth/account/views.py you'll see the definition of signup as `signup = SignupView.as_view()`. So let's override `SignupView` to use our own form and then use our class view for the `account_sigunp` !

Here's how to do it:

a. Create your custom view that inherits `SignupView` and overrides the form class

```
class CustomFormSignupView(allauth.accounts.views.SignupView):
    form_class = CustomSignupForm
```

b. Create a custom form that inherits from `SignupForm` and overrides the email validation message

```
class CustomSignupForm(allauth.accounts.forms.SignupForm ):
    def raise_duplicate_email_error(self):
        # here I tried to override the method, but it is not called
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            _("An account already exists with this e-mail address."
              " Please sign in to that account."))
```

c. In your own urls.py add the following *after* `include('allauth.urls')` to override the `account_signup` url

```
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r"^accounts/signup/$", CustomFormSignupView.as_view(), name="account_signup"),``
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However the ``BaseSignupForm`` is derived from the ``_base_signup_form_class()`` function, that itself imports the form class defined in the ``SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS`` setting, which would be my form above. So it would effectively try to import itself.

Comment: As this is a `ValidationError`, it pops up only after user submitted a form with additional information. It's ok because they should be aware that they already have an account, but wouldn't it be better if the form didn't display at all and allauth just redirected to login with a message "An account already exists with this e-mail address. Please sign in to that account first, then connect your ... account."

Comment: Or just log the user in and auto connect social account. This would be secure with Google oath, not sure about others. It requires setting AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND manually as it's a passwords login.

Comment: ... as it's a passwordless login: `user.backend = settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS[0]` and `login(request, user)`.

Answer (score 0):

After creating your CustomSignupForm(allauth.accounts.forms.SignupForm ) that overrides the raise_duplicate_email_error method, you can, with [django-allauth](/questions/tagged/django-allauth) version 0.18, add the following to your settings file:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'signup': 'path.to.your.custom.social.signup.form.CustomSignupForm'
}
```

The new raise_duplicate_email_error method should be called now.

Hope this helps you.